# ¿Como incrementar el valor de un div? jquery

Tags: html, jquery

estoy haciendo un botón que al presionarlo se incremente el numero, pero solo queda en 1 y no avanza:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   

$(".incrementar").click(function(){

        let contador = 0;

        contador++;

        $(".contador").text(contador);


   })


})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contador.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="contador">0</div>
    <input type="submit" class="incrementar" value="aumentar">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que al llamar la función, estas reasignando el valor a 0 otra vez y lo sumas otra vez, la solución seria la siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   var contador = 0;

$(".incrementar").click(function(){

        contador++;

        $(".contador").text(contador);


   })


})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contador.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="contador">0</div>
    <input type="submit" class="incrementar" value="aumentar">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu `variable` esta dentro de la `función` del `botón`, por lo que siempre llegará solo al **1**, lo que tienes que hacer es declarar esa `variable` fuera del `evento click` de tu `botón`, debería quedar así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var contador = 0;

  $(".incrementar").click(function(){
     contador++;
    $(".contador").text(contador);
  });

});
```